# Multiply array elements by the array length: Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out why my program will not work. What I am essentially trying to do is multiply each element of an array, by the length of that particular array. For example, if the input is an array of
[2, 3, 1, 0]
it will yield this
[8, 12, 4, 0]

here is my program

```
public class Challenge {
    public static int[] MultiplyByLength(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){
            return arr[i] * arr.length;
        }
    }
}
```

any criticism is appreciated in advance!

Comment: you calculate and get a new value，then you need to store the new value into array,like `arr[i] = newvalue`

Answer (score 0):

Set the values and return **after** the loop. Method names, by convention, start with a lowercase letter. And you have an array indexing error. Fixing all of that might look something like,

```
public static int[] multiplyByLength(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] *= arr.length;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Wow, so simple yet I was stuck on this for a while. Thank you a lot! One part I do not understand still that maybe you could shed some light on it why you use " *= " on line 3?

Comment: It's a short form for `arr[i] = arr[i] * arr.length;`

Comment: Side note: You don't need to return the array here as it will already be modified.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid mistakes like this you can use java streams

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Challenge {
    public static int[] MultiplyByLength(int[] arr) {
        return Arrays.stream(arr).map(i -> i * arr.length).toArray();
    }
}
```